# DB2 SQL Resultset Limited to Lookup Filter

Tags: sql, db2

Lookup String: 41031052-1
How can I modify the following SQL statement to only get the different configuration of the Lookup string.

```
Select Distinct t1.itnbr As itemno
From amflib1.itmrva t1
Join amflib1.whsmst t2 On t2.STID = t1.STID And t2.whid In('100','200','888')
Join amflib1.itembl t3 On t3.itnbr = t1.itnbr And t3.house = t2.whid And t3.planib >= 0
Where t1.itnbr Like '41031052-1%' And t1.itcls <> 'TOOL' Order By 1
```

The current Resultset:

```
ITEMNO
 ---------------
 41031052-1     
 41031052-1    F
 41031052-10    
 41031052-11    
 41031052-11   F
 41031052-12    
 41031052-12   F
 41031052-13    
 41031052-13   F
 41031052-14    
 41031052-14   F
 41031052-15    
 41031052-15   F
 41031052-17    
 41031052-17   F
 41031052-19    
 41031052-19   F
```

Desired Resultset:

```
ITEMNO
 ---------------
 41031052-1     
 41031052-1    F
```

Comment: Wouldn't that fail to yield the 41031052-1    F in the Resultset?

Comment: Also in some cases there might be configs like 41031052-1A, 41031052-1B1, etc.

Comment: patterns can be made best in regular expressions, but you need stable patterns for that to work, or you need to generate at all times all a special regex for all ocaasion

Comment: Did I get it right, that the rule is: "delete a substring after `41031052-1` ending with spaces and concatenated it with 2-nd part of the original string after spaces"? What's the number of spaces you need before `F` in the result? This number is different for, say, `41031052-1  F` and `41031052-11 F` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can help with such patterns

this would only show your wanted result, with your test data as you have only 2 digit number and teh regexp excludes a that ahave a number after `41031052-1`

This needs to be adaopted, if the patterns change

here you can test pattern https://regex101.com/

and here are more about regular expressions https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-regexp-like

```
Select Distinct t1.itnbr As itemno
From amflib1.itmrva t1
Join amflib1.whsmst t2 On t2.STID = t1.STID And t2.whid In('100','200','888')
Join amflib1.itembl t3 On t3.itnbr = t1.itnbr And t3.house = t2.whid And t3.planib >= 0
Where REGEXP_LIKE(t1.itnbr,'^41031052-1[^0-9].*')  And t1.itcls <> 'TOOL'
Order By 1
```

Comment: It appears that our iSeries version 7.2 does not support the REGEXP_LIKE DB2 function.

Comment: `For IBM i 7.1, TR9 must be installed and for IBM i 7.2, TR1 must be installed.`  see https://www.itjungle.com/2015/05/19/fhg051915-story01/